# always @ (posedge clk ) not triggering as expected

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

**always block is not triggering continuously**

```
always@(posedge clk) begin
    for (int i=1;i<=32;i=i+1) begin
       clk_a=i;
       #0.3215
    end
    for (int j=31;j>=0;j=j-1) begin
       clk_a=j;
       #0.3215
    end
    clk_a=0;
    end
```

In 5th clk always block is not triggered ||y for 7th and 9th clocks and this behavior is happening randomly through the simulation. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1/ What is the frequency of your clk. 2/ What is your `timescale set to?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your time precision is small enough so that `0.3215` is not getting rounded to `0.322`. Also I assume you have typos in your two `for` loops.

First loop: `i<=32` should be `i<32`
Second loop: `j=j+1` should be `j--`.

The only other possible explanation is you have a race condition with the end of the second loop and the next `@(posedge clk)`. You should try:

```
initial @(posedge clk) 
  forever begin
    for (int i=0;i<32;i++) begin
       clk_a=i;
       #0.3215
    end
    for (int j=31;j>=0;j--) begin
       clk_a=j;
       #0.3215
    end
    clk_a=0;
  end
```

Comment: Yes, it was a typo mistake. I made the changes to the above code

Comment: @Rahul, what about the first loop? and what is the frequency of clk?

Comment: Hi dave , frequency of the clk is variable, I have kept a constant value for now

Comment: And that constant value is....? Does my answer make any sense to you?

Comment: Yes, dave , Thnak You